# Angular 2 Router 3, how to keep the component on routing

Tags: angular2-routing

http://plnkr.co/edit/x65Mp5SPu4dIRrdNzYfc

```
export class ContactsListComponent implements OnInit {
    contacts: Contact[];
    constructor(private contactsService: ContactsService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        // If user presses "back"button from details page, it always initialize it again.
        this.contacts = this.contactsService.getContacts();
    }.....
```

As you can see from the above plunk codes, there is an contacts app. First page shows contact list, and if user clicks an contact, it will route to detail contact page.

If user clicks "back" button at the detail contact page, Angular recreates List page and call "contactsService.getContacts()" again.

I'd like to make it reuse "List component" instead of recreating and calling "contactsService.getContacts()" anymore.

I found old router supported "CanReuse", but new router(v3) doesn't anymore.
Is there any way to achieve this with new Router(v3)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Does anybody knows how to solve this without using services?